# Errno 9 Bad file descriptor In Python on using file.close() function

Tags: python

On running the code below every time I'm confronted with the error:

"OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor"

at the lines of f.flush() and f.close(). Commenting out the f.flush() and f.close() lines seems to fix this error, but I still don't understand why exactly the problem is occurring.

```py
import numpy as np
#import math
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nex

def creator(self):      #Creating an Adjaceny Matrix From Given CSV
        print("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))
        if(os.path.isdir("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))==False):
            os.mkdir("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))
        os.chdir("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))
        f=open("%s_AdjList.txt" %(self.string), 'w')

        for i in range(0, len(self.foodweb)):
            m=0
            f.write("%d" %(i))
            for j in self.foodweb[i,:]:
                if j>0:
                    f.write(" %d" %(m))
                m+=1
            f.write("\n")
        f.flush()
        f.close()
```

Additionally when I opened another file (in the same script) in 'rb' mode and flushed and closed it after reading it, there was no problem. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```py
def plotter(self):

        print(self.foodweb.shape)
        g=open("%s_AdjList.txt" %(self.string),'rb')
        self.DirGraph=nex.read_adjlist(g, create_using=nex.DiGraph)
        nex.draw_networkx(self.DirGraph)
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.show()
        plt.close()
        g.flush()
        g.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try open the full path

```
"AdjacenyList\%s\s_AdjList.txt" %(self.string)
```

you are missing \ try `f = open("\%s_AdjList.txt" % (self.string), 'w')`

can you plese extract `"AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string)` and the open directory `"\%s_AdjList.txt" % (self.string)` to variables and print them ? and verify that they are the same ? (not include file name)?

Comment: Hello. Adding the extra \ leads the compiler to throw up the error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\fw_tuesday_lake_AdjList.txt'

Comment: i edited my answer please share this 2 variables , also it is standart that you don't have permission to / directory which is root directory something in the path is not well concatenate, try use os.path.join() instead of string concatenation

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the input. Seems like Ransomware Protection on my Windows 10 laptop was switched on, due to which permission to access the file directory was denied. Switching it off removed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an addition to the answer of [junior_software](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56218803/7545157)

---

Always use context manager for filehandling. It is just more safe in terms of opening and close data streams to static memory.

```py
def creator(self):      #Creating an Adjaceny Matrix From Given CSV
    print("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))
    if(os.path.isdir("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))==False):
         os.mkdir("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))
    os.chdir("AdjacenyList\%s" %(self.string))

    with open("%s_AdjList.txt" %(self.string), 'w') as f:
        for i in range(0, len(self.foodweb)):
            m=0
            f.write("%d" %(i))
            for j in self.foodweb[i,:]:
                if j>0:
                    f.write(" %d" %(m))
                m+=1
            f.write("\n")
```